# Install Xfce & remove Gnome

Tags: boot, bootloader, boot-repair, secure-boot

I have installed xfce on ubuntu & removed gnome. Now its  not booting up please give me suggestions to do correction to my pc

Comment: By removing GNOME, depending on what you removed, you may have broken your system. Do a clean reinstall of what you actually want so that you don't have to "remove" anything later and break things again.

Comment: now what should i do in order to boot up my pc & how to do clean reinstall of xcef desktop

Comment: Download the Xubuntu iso if you want Xfce, make a bootable USB using whichever means you want. When attempting to start the computer, change the boot option to USB, test out Xubuntu, and if you like it, click on the "install now" icon on the desktop to start the actual installation. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu and other links there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* do you see during the boot process? If the screen is black or doesn't show anything recognisable, what's the last recognisable thing on the screen before that? (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be that the GUI is damaged. Just check whether terminal based login is possible by pressing ctrl+alt+f1 or f2. Then you may be able to rescue the X11. If that is not the case the other solutions may be the recourse left.